# Javascript get an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, get

I am trying to use api for bitfinex website. for prices of bitcoin. with this code.

`https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD`

I receive this

`[["tBTCUSD",11437,106.37262285,11438,63.64002459,595,0.0549,11437,28751.21271922,11487,10771]]`

I used this code to get it out of the link.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD", function(data){

    });
});
```

problem I am beginner in javascript, I looked at W3School for javascript array, and seem that i receive information as an array. or some format as an array.[W3School | JavaScript Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp). Array begin and end with `[]` yet in the receive info there is double brackets.

what I am looking at? and how to handle?

Comment: you're getting an array which has one element and this element is another array

Comment: they gave you a nested array (array inside array). I'm not sure why, you should check the API docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at a 2d array.

You can retrieve `"tBTCUSD"` with `data[0][0]` and `11437` with `data[0][1]`, etc.

Comment: you are right, I could request multiple arraies at once, `https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD,tXRPUSD` and `data[0][0]` is `"tBTCUSD"` and `data[1][0]` would be `"tXRPUSD"`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it.Using spread syntax is one of the the way. Spread syntax will remove the inner array. For example `[[1,2,3]]` will be `[1,2,3]`;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD", function(data) {
    console.log(...data); // using spread operator
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: is it an array then? how to use it?

Comment: @AbdullahSalma i didn't get you. `data` is an array of array.I guess you are looking to remove the inner array

Answer (score 0):

It is something like array in an array, so to get an array use it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD", function(data){
        var arrayElements = data[0]; // First index
        console.log(arrayElements); // You will get an array
    });
});
```

Try it !

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an array of arrays. Since you only ask for one symbol the array of symbols contains only one result. Not sure what else to tell you, try asking for two symbols. You should get [[symbol 1],[symbol 2]].

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an a two dimensional array in response. You can use [`Destructuring Assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get a 1-D array:

Consider a 2D array:

```
let arr_2D = [[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']];
let [arr_1D] = arr_2D;

console.log(arr_1D);
 // Expected output: [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD", function(response) {
        let [data] = response;
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```